# Change background color of ListView item from Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a `Fragment` that is implementing a `ListView`. I have a global reference of this `ListView` in the `Fragment`class and i want to change the background color of the `ListView` item in `updateStep(int position)` method. I don't want to change the color of every item in the list. I am doing some processing in the Fragment and i want to change the color of the `ListView` item accordingly.

My `updateStep` method is simple:

```
public void updateStep(int position) {
        if(stepsListView != null)
             stepsListView.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);    
}
```

But the `getChildAt(position)` is returning null.What is the other way to get the item and update the color of an item.

The list_item.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="8dp">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/standard_text_size"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:text="@string/about_text_default"
        android:id="@+id/text_list_item">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:text="@string/about_text_default"
        android:id="@+id/test_list_item_description">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the fragment (that has a list) looks like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.carmanah.views.fragments.TestListFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_heading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="@dimen/standard_heading_text_size"
            android:text="@string/heading_text_tests">

        </TextView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/task_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/standard_text_size"
            android:divider="@color/gray"
            android:dividerHeight="2dip">

        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

P.S. I am using `CustomArrayAdapter` for this list.

Answer (score 1):

You can get only visible View from ListView because row views in ListView are reuseable. So, you should control the item position.

The below method helps you to get the view.

```
public View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {
    final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

    if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition ) {
        return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
    } else {
        final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
        return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
    }
}
```

You can change background color of the item like this:

```
public void updateStep(int position) {
        if(stepsListView != null)
             getViewByPosition(position, stepsListView).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I can get the View by your method but apparently `setBackgroundColor(Color.Green)` method is not reflecting change. Do you think that i need to call some notify method or something else?

Comment: hmm, after this line, maybe repaint() or notifyDataSetChanged(); method can be used for it. But I don't think it is necessary.

Comment: It is not reflecting the change using just `setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)`. I have tried `invalidate()` and `((CustomAdapter) stepsListView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged()` on `stepsListView` but it is not working either.

Comment: Maybe It actually changes but you can not see the color because of the child view of list item. As you know that if there is a child view that width and height attributes are match_parent, then you should change the background color of the child view to be able to display the color on the list item. Just publish your list item xml with us.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have edited the question. Do let me know the process of changing the childview's background color.

Answer (score 0):

The other way to get the item & update the color of the same is by assigning the color in the getView method of your Custom Array Adapter. Juts make a Relative/Linear Layout having all the components and assign the color using the following statement:-

```
viewHolder.lin_item.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

where lin_item is the Liner Layout inside the ViewHolder & you can assign the color according to any condition of your choice.

The getView method already has position, so no need to worry about that.

Comment: I don't want to change the color of every item in the list. I am doing some processing in the Fragment and i want to change the color of the ListView item accordingly. Sorry i didn't mention it before.

Comment: You can do your processing inside the getView method as you can't modify the color of each item in ListView from outside this method. One thing is possible that you can pass the Array List as arguments in updateStep & then run an iterator accordingly.